# how i can apply the ARRAYFORMULA function on the " =SOMME(....)"

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

how i can apply the ARRAYFORMULA function on the function

```
=SOMME(filter($A$2:B;$A$2:A=INDIRECT("E"&LIGNE()))
```

**I want to get the same result of column F in column G**

Answer (score 1):

Delete your formulas from Col E, Col F and Col G.

Then place the following formula in, say, cell E2:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A2:B};"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) '' "))`

This version would produce the same result...

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(A2:B;"Select A, SUM(B) WHERE A Is Not Null GROUP BY A LABEL SUM(B) '' "))`

... but I always recommend using the first version, just incase data in the target columns ever moves (e.g., if you were to insert a column before Col A, making the old A and B become B and C, the second formula would break while the first would not).